# No sign-out authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Identity.TwoFactorUserId'

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

ASP.NET Core 2.2 web app using code migrated from full fat MVC app.

My `AccountController` contains this simple code for its `Logout` route.

```
await this.SignInManager.SignOutAsync();
return this.RedirectToAction(nameof(Landing.HomeController.Index), "Home");
```

But this gives.

> No sign-out authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Identity.TwoFactorUserId'.

Pretty confusing given that I've never mentioned 2FA in my code, and Google login is working.

```
serviceCollection
    .AddIdentityCore<MyUser>(identityOptions =>
    {
        identityOptions.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    })
    .AddUserStore<MyUserStore>()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<MyUser>>();

serviceCollection.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    })
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        this.Configuration.Bind("OAuth2:Providers:Google", googleOptions);

        googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub", "string");
    })
    .AddExternalCookie();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a complement to [@Luke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56744102/10091607):

The reason why `SignInManager::SignOutAsync()` throws is this method will also sign out the `TwoFactorUserIdScheme` behind the scenes:

```
public virtual async Task SignOutAsync()
{
    await Context.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
    await Context.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
    await Context.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme);
}
```

(See [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5ace0efa495c1faa61c8138699f31a830c676ca5/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L246-L251))

Typically, these tree authentication schemes are registered **automatically** by **`AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>()`**:

```
public static IdentityBuilder AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
    ...
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme, o =>
    {
        o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme;
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    });
    ... // other services
}
```

(See [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/f3f9a1cdbcd06b298035b523732b9f45b1408461/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L72) )

However, you added the `Identity` services by **`AddIdentityCore<>()`** instead of the `AddIdentity<>()`.

Because the `AddIdentityCore<>()` doesn't register a `TwoFactorUserIdScheme` scheme (see [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5ace0efa495c1faa61c8138699f31a830c676ca5/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L33-L56)) automatically, there's no associated `CookieAuthenticationHandler` for `TwoFactorUserIdScheme`. As a result,  it throws.

---

**How to solve**

In order to work with `SignInManager.SignOutAsync()`, according to above description, we need ensure a `<scheme>-<handler>` map has been registed for `TwoFactorUserIdScheme` .

So I change your code as below, now it works fine for me:

```
serviceCollection.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    })
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme, o =>
    {
        o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme;
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    })
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        this.Configuration.Bind("OAuth2:Providers:Google", googleOptions);
        googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub", "string");
    })
    .AddExternalCookie();
```

Comment: It's a great answer, thanks. I have often had to look at the source code on GitHub to work out how to use the API, which is a big problem with the design, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can create your own `SignInManager<MyUser>` and override sign out as you need

```
public class CustomSignInManager : SignInManager<MyUser>
{
    public override async Task SignOutAsync()
    {    
        await Context.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
        await Context.SignOutAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
}
```

Then change `AddSignInManager<SignInManager<MyUser>>()` to `AddSignInManager<CustomSignInManager>()` in your `Startup` class

```
serviceCollection
    .AddIdentityCore<MyUser>(identityOptions =>
    {
        identityOptions.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    })
    .AddUserStore<MyUserStore>()
    .AddSignInManager<CustomSignInManager>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Below code works for me , use the same AuthenticationScheme that you use while "AddAuthentication" in startup.cs

```cs
[HttpGet("signout")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task signout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    var prop = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "/logout-complete"
    };
    // after signout this will redirect to your provided target
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, prop);
}

[HttpGet("logout-complete")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public string logoutComplete()
{
    return "logout-complete";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the `SignOutAsync` method on a `SignInManager<T>` you've injected into the controller. Instead, use the method on the `HttpContext` which takes a `scheme` argument. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with itminus reply, We would get an error because in .net core 3.0 if we use AddIdentityCore<>() instead of AddIdentity<>() we would get an error. But when upgrading to .net 7.0 if we again use AddIdentityCore<>() instead of AddIdentity<>() we would get the same error for Identity.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme as well that I am faced with after upgrading. For SignInManager we require Identity.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme as well otherwise we get an error.

The solution which I applied in mine .net 7.0 project is:
Instead of adding every scheme and handler by yourself, we can just use

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityCookies();
```

This will add all the schemes handlers for you and at the time of signout we need to should use below:

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);  
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);  
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme);
```